# Yii2 form validation - compare password repeat only when password field is filled

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

My form validation uses the following rules:

```
[['password', 'password_repeat'], 'required'],
['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'message' => "Passwords don't match"],
```

How to write rules for `password_repeat` to compare it with `password` only if user fill `password` field. If user skip `password`, validation for `password_repeat` should be also skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scenarios](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios) for that:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['username', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN],
        [['username', 'password', 'password_repeat'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        [
            'password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password',
            'message' => "Passwords don't match", 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER,
        ],
    ];
}
```

This allows you to set different rules for different forms (different fields required on login and registration).

You may also consider creating different models for different forms with own `rules()`, like `LoginForm` and `RegisterForm`. This is actually more clean solution and gives more control.

---

**EDIT**

For conditional rules you should use [`when`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$when-detail) property:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['password', 'password_repeat'], 'string'],
        [
            'password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password',
            'message' => "Passwords don't match", 'skipOnEmpty' => false,
            'when' => function ($model) {
                return $model->password !== null && $model->password !== '';
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: password and passwrod_repeat part of user profile settings, if user want change password, enter password and this repeat, otherwise, skip paasword and password_repeat, i want just if user insert password, check password_repeat field.

Comment: i used your code, but when user insert password_repeat compar two field, and when user insert password and skip password_repeat, don't compar two field, i even use custom function for validation, but it also work just when password_repeat is not empty!