# yii2, use model rules when input is checked

Tags: yii2

New to yii2 so im trying to figure out how to use the required rule but only when a certain field is checked, as the form is has a radio field which allows a new user to create an account as a personal account or as a business account.

I have used use_vat_number as an sample radio button.

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        ['vat_number', 'required' , 'when' => use_vat_number = 1],//the idea
    ];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii2 form validation compare password repeat just when insert password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389866/yii2-form-validation-compare-password-repeat-just-when-insert-password)

Comment: not a duplicate my friend ;-)

Comment: well it uses the conditional validation which is also suggested as annswer , but above all you got the answer and that matters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Yii2 when and whenClient property](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$when-detail)

```
public function rules() {
   return [
       ['vat_number', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
            return $model->use_vat_number == 1;
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
               var opValue = $('input:radio[name=\\'Here Radio Button Name\\']:checked').val();
               return opValue==1;
            }",
        ],
   ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use anonymous function to configure [`when`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$when-detail) property:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [
            'vat_number', 'required' , 
            'when' => function ($model) {
                 return $model->use_vat_number == 1;
            },
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Showing an error with this solution, you forgot the ;

Comment: @user759235 Fixed.